# NServiceBus - mixed RabbitMq and Msmq transports in single service

Tags: nservicebus

We are using NSB 6.0. We have a windows service pulling messages from RabbitMq and when these messages are handled (within the same service) we would like to publish a new event out to the Msmq transport.

I have tried to configure multiple endpoints using [this approach](https://docs.particular.net/samples/hosting/multi-hosting/), within the single windows service. One endpoint configured with the RabbitMqTransport, and one endpoint configured with the MsmqTransport.  However, when the code to configure the Msmq endpoint is run this exception is raised: 
     `"The given key (RabbitMQ.RoutingTopologySupportsDelayedDelivery) was not present in the dictionary.'"` 
 So my question: is it possible to host NSB RabbitMq and Msmq transports within a single service? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [SQL - MSMQ bridge](https://docs.particular.net/samples/sql-bridge/) and also look at the [Bridge community component](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/bridge/).

Between the two of them you should have enough info to build your solution.

Ping me if you need more help

Comment: Note that https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/bridge/ is now available, and is designed for exactly this purpose